# How to give default GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS while running docker image locally?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, credentials

I have migrated my Flask python project to FastApi and I want to deploy the new application to Google Cloud Run , I'm trying to test my docker image locally but I got an error that I need to set credentials it cannot get by default. So is there any way to run the image and test it locally without generate a service account.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
# Start from the official slim Python base image.
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the current working directory to /code.
#This is where we'll put the requirements.txt file and the app directory.
WORKDIR /code

# Copy the file with the requirements to the /code directory.
# Copy only the file with the requirements first, not the rest of the code.
# As this file doesn't change often, Docker will detect it and use the cache for this step, enabling the cache for the next step too.
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

# Install the package dependencies in the requirements file.
# The --no-cache-dir option tells pip to not save the downloaded packages locally,
# as that is only if pip was going to be run again to install the same packages,
# but that's not the case when working with containers.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

# As this has all the code which is what changes most frequently the Docker
# cache won't be used for this or any following steps easily
COPY ./app /code/app

# Because the program will be started at /code and inside of it is the directory ./app with your code,
# Uvicorn will be able to see and import app from app.main.
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

**Docker Commands:**

```
docker build -t gcr.io/cog-dev/serving-fastapi .
```

```
docker run -d --name mycontainer -p 80:80 gcr.io/cog-dev/serving-fastapi
```

**The error I get in Docker Desktop logs:**

```
raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: 
Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

> Note that locally the application run without any service account the credentials got by default

Comment: Guillaume Blaquiere wrote a good article that explains how: https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da